# Discontinuous function extended as a distribution

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^\star\to\mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function on its domain, and suppose : $$\exists m\in\mathbb{N}^\star,\;\exists c>0\;/\;\forall x\in[-1,1]\setminus\lbrace0\rbrace,\;|f(x)|\leqslant\frac{c}{|x|^m}$$

The goal is to prove that there exists a distribution $T_f\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ that extends $f$ to $\mathbb{R}$, in the sense that if $\varphi\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^\star)$ is a test function whose support does not contain $0$, then $<T_f,\varphi>=<f,\varphi>$.

Knowing that the principal values are given as : $$<\text{vp}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),\varphi>=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\int_{|x|>\varepsilon}\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}\text{d}x$$ and : $$<\text{vp}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right),\varphi>=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\left(\int_{|x|>\varepsilon}\frac{\varphi(x)}{x^2}\text{d}x-\frac{2\varphi(0)}{\varepsilon}\right),$$
I would be tempted to look for $T_f$ as something like : $$<T_f,\varphi>=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\left(\int_{|x|>\varepsilon}f(x)\varphi(x)\text{d}x-\beta_\varepsilon(\varphi)\right)$$

Does anyone know something about this ? I can find no litterature, and I have no clue what the $\beta_\varepsilon(\varphi)$ would be besides a sum of coefficients of the form $\displaystyle\frac{\lambda\varphi^{(k)}(0)}{\varepsilon^\ell}$.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and pro tips !

Comment: Look at $T_{f,\psi,M}(\varphi) = \langle f, \varphi - \psi \sum_{k=0}^M \frac{\varphi^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k\rangle$ where you have fixed some $\psi \in C^\infty_c$ constant on $[-a,a]$. The principal value of $1/x$ is obtained with $M=0$ and $\psi$ even.

Comment: @reuns Is the goal to try to take $a\to0^+$ afterwards ? :)

Comment: No ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @reuns okay I get it for vp(1/x) ! For vp(1/x²), I need to take $M=1$ and $\psi$ even as well, but I don't know what to ask more... Btw, $\psi$ has to be constant equal to $1$ on a neighboor of $0$ right ? Do I have to make $a\to+\infty$ ?! :O

Comment: ?? Why don't you want to keep $a$ fixed finite non-zero ? Do you see why $\varphi \mapsto \varphi - \psi \sum_{k=0}^M \frac{\varphi^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$ is a continuous linear map $C^\infty_c \to C^\infty_c$ ? Thus composing with distributions (continuous linear forms) works well. Yes $\psi$ is constant $=1$ on $[a,a]$ (or at least $\psi(0) = 1,\psi^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for $1 \le k \le M$) and $M \ge m-1$. I would ask what are the distributional derivatives of $T_{1/x,\psi,M}$, to obtain a formula for all the derivatives of $vp(1/x)$.

Comment: @reuns Okay, it works perfectly ! Thanks a lot !